# error: "No compiler for language C#"

Tags: c#, mono

An ASP.NET/C# project which I created in 2003 has been running on a university server for over 10 years now but I was just informed that the server crashed and they are trying to set everything up again.

They are getting the following error.

I see that at the bottom it seems that they have installed Mono on a Debian machine. Could it be that they installed Mono but forgot to install the C# compiler, or does this message imply something else is wrong?

What could be the cause and solution to this error?

[image]

Comment: Look in web.config file and ensure that C# is registered in the `<compilers>` node.  You'd find google hits like this by googling "no compiler for language".  Takes you to the question about boo.

Answer (score 3):

According to the `BuildManager` code in Mono:

```
if (configSection == null)
    config = WebConfigurationManager.GetWebApplicationSection ("system.web/compilation") as CompilationSection;
    else
    config = configSection;

...

if (throwOnMissing)
throw new HttpException (String.Concat ("No compiler for language '", language, "'."));
```

It's apparently not finding the compilation section for C# in the configuration.  Have you checked the machine.config or web.config? e.g.

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="C#">
      <compilers>
         You should have a .NET compiler configuration here.
      </compilers>
    </compilation>    
  </system.web>
```

Check out [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_ASP.NET) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

it could be also an decode error because he can identify '\C#\' try to use dos2unix rekursivly over your directory